# Steady State Solution of a 1D Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, steady-state

I was given the 1D heat equation

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=u+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$

with the boundary conditions of

$0 < x < \pi$ , $u(0,t)=0$ , $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\pi,t)=0$ , $u(x,0)=f(x)$

I was then instructed to solve the BVP which I did, but I was also asked the following:

"Find the stead state solution if it exists"

If the 1D heat equation was just

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$

I could most definitely say yes there is a stead state solution and call $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$ but since there is an added $u$ in the middle I am not entirely sure.

If there is a steady state solution I do not know how to approach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Andrew